# Call Xinitthreads from Java. Gnuplot error

Tags: java, linux, scala, gnuplot

I'm trying to start gnuplot from my Scala code.

I start an external process a [ProcessBuilder](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder)

However, when I start gnuplot:

```
gnuplot -p <generated script>
```

so, as in:

```
Seq("gnuplot", "-p", scriptname).!
```

I get:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
gnuplot: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
```

It seems that I need to call [XInitThreads](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/XInitThreads.html)

My questions is:

- How to call that native method from Java (I'm assuming I can then use that in my Scala code) or how do you do that directly from Scala?
- Could there be another problem?

EDIT:
I don't understand why it is such a pain to do simple things like that. I don't want to spend the entire day digging into the finest details just to plot a frigging graph.
I simply switched to using JFreeChart.

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you are spawning the child process? I assume if you run the command from the shell (using the generated script) it works, right? Can you provide a snippet the Scala code launching the process that fails?

Comment: Start by having a look at this thread: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2000-October/msg00021.html to understand what's happening. Is the JVM running your code launched from some other process that has already opened the X connection (in which case you need to dig upstream)? Also, which toolkit is gnuplot itself using for rendering? For example see http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/crash-when-using-wxt-in-Ubuntu-12-04-td17318.html of failing to call XInitThreads.

Comment: One last comment: as far as I know, when the JVM accesses X, it always cals this function early enough; so I don't think it's something "you" do in your code that causes this, and there is also no point in calling it yourself (each client must call it early enough). Sorry I can't help more... Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this tip by Eggplanticus from [here](http://theindiestone.com/forums/index.php?/topic/1044-damn-you-linuxjava/&do=findComment&comment=15829).

fixXInitThreads.cpp

```
#include <Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
class a{public: a() { XInitThreads(); }};a X;
```

compile with:
`g++ -o libfixXInitThreads.so -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libxx.so -L/usr/lib/X11 -I/usr/include/X11 fixXInitThreads.cpp -lX11`

and at the 1st line of your `main()` put this:
`System.loadLibrary("fixXInitThreads");`
or at local path:
`System.load(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/libfixXInitThreads.so");`